# Hotw to use symbols in geom_point in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

A small sample of the data is:

```
df<-read.table (text=" N    SO  Value
1   A1  12
2   A1  14
3   A1  16
4   A1  18
5   A1  20
6   B1  22
7   B1  24
8   B1  26
9   B1  28
10  B1  30

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to use the greek symbol of alpha (α)  and  beta (β) instead of red and blue circles on the lines

I have used these codes:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=N,y=Value)) +geom_point(size=3,aes(colour=SO)) +geom_line(aes(colour = SO))
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_text` with the option `parse = TRUE` to add symbols as labels.

Assuming that you want alpha where SO = A1 and beta where SO = B1, something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(SO == "A1", "alpha", "beta")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(N, Value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = SO)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label), parse = TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question and it would be good if I could use my own codes

Comment: Slightly edited my answer, although your edit made no difference to the code: if A1 then alpha, otherwise beta, assuming the only options are "A1" and "something else". You can always change the mutate/if_else according to whatever coding you use.

Comment: What do you mean by "my codes" ? If you mean the R code in your question, that won't work because you need to use `geom_text` instead of `geom_point`. Otherwise please clarify what you mean.